# Char-RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to get a simple RNN to work in tensorflow, but I'm having several problems with it.

What I'm trying to do for now, is to simply run a forward pass of the RNN with an LSTM as its cell type.

I have scraped some news articles and want to feed them into the RNN. I have split the string, which consists of the concatenation of all articles, into chars and mapped the chars to integers. Then I have one-hot encoded those integers.

```
data = [c for c in article]
chars = list(set(data))
idx_chars = {i:ch for i,ch in enumerate(chars)}
chars_idx = {ch:i for i,ch in enumerate(chars)}
int_data = [chars_idx[ch] for ch in data]

# config values
vocab_size = len(chars)
hidden_size = 100
seq_length = 25

# helper function to get one-hot encoding

def onehot(value):
    result = np.zeros(vocab_size)
    result[value] = 1
    return result

def vectorize_input(inputs):
    result = [onehot(x) for x in inputs]
    return result

input = vectorize_input(int_data[:25])
```

Now for the tensorflow code. I want to run through all the characters in the data and use 25 characters for each forward pass.
My first question is with regards to the batch size, if I want to do this the way I just mentioned, my batch size is 1, right? So each vector that corresponds to one char in the input has shape [1,vocab_size] and there are 25 of those vectors in my input. So I have used the following tensors:

```
seq_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [seq_length, 1, vocab_size])
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [seq_length, 1, vocab_size])
inputs = [tf.reshape(i,(1,vocab_size)) for i in tf.split(0,seq_length,seq_input)]
```

I had to create the last tensor, because thats the format that the rnn function expects.

Then I encountered a problem with the variable scope, I get the error below:

```
cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, input_size = vocab_size)
# note: first argument of zero_state is the batch_size
initial_state = cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32)
outputs, state = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state= initial_state)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([outputs, state], feed_dict = {inputs:input})

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-449af38c387d> in <module>()
      7     # note: first argument of zero_state is supposed to be batch_size
      8     initial_state = cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32)
----> 9     outputs, state = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state= initial_state)
     10 
     11 sess = tf.Session()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state, dtype, sequence_length, scope)
    124             zero_output, state, call_cell)
    125       else:
--> 126         (output, state) = call_cell()
    127 
    128       outputs.append(output)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in <lambda>()
    117       if time > 0: vs.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    118       # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop
--> 119       call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
    120       # pylint: enable=cell-var-from-loop
    121       if sequence_length:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.pyc in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    200       # Parameters of gates are concatenated into one multiply for efficiency.
    201       c, h = array_ops.split(1, 2, state)
--> 202       concat = linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True)
    203 
    204       # i = input_gate, j = new_input, f = forget_gate, o = output_gate

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.pyc in linear(args, output_size, bias, bias_start, scope)
    700   # Now the computation.
    701   with vs.variable_scope(scope or "Linear"):
--> 702     matrix = vs.get_variable("Matrix", [total_arg_size, output_size])
    703     if len(args) == 1:
    704       res = math_ops.matmul(args[0], matrix)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in get_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, trainable, collections)
    254   return get_variable_scope().get_variable(_get_default_variable_store(), name,
    255                                            shape, dtype, initializer,
--> 256                                            trainable, collections)
    257 
    258 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in get_variable(self, var_store, name, shape, dtype, initializer, trainable, collections)
    186     with ops.name_scope(None):
    187       return var_store.get_variable(full_name, shape, dtype, initializer,
--> 188                                     self.reuse, trainable, collections)
    189 
    190 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in get_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, reuse, trainable, collections)
     99       if should_check and not reuse:
    100         raise ValueError("Over-sharing: Variable %s already exists, disallowed."
--> 101                          " Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?" % name)
    102       found_var = self._vars[name]
    103       if not shape.is_compatible_with(found_var.get_shape()):

ValueError: Over-sharing: Variable forward/RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?
```

And I'm not sure why I get this error, because I actually haven't specified any variables in my code, the variables are only created inside the rnn and rnn_cell functions, can someone tell me how to fix this error?

Another error I'm currently getting is a type error, since my input is of type tf.int32, but the hidden layer that is created inside the LSTM is of type tf.float32 and the Linear function inside the rnn_cell.py code, concatenates those two tensor and multiplies them by a weight matrix. Why is this not possible, I'd assume that it's relatively common for input to be one-hot encoded and thus having type int32?

In general, is this approach of having a batch size of 1 standard when training char-rnns? I've only seen code by Andrej Karpathy, where he trains a char-rnn in basic numpy and he uses the same procedure, where he simply goes through the whole text in sequences of length 25. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086

Comment: I'm almost certain this error is being raised because an existing (perhaps partial) execution of the same commands in your IPython session has left some variables behind. The easiest thing to do would be to run `tf.reset_default_graph()` before running this cell. (You will have to recreate the `seq_input`, `targets` and `input` tensors after running this function, because all existing tensors will be invalidated.)

Comment: That was the problem, thanks for your help.

Comment: @eager2learn Will you share your code? I came looking for karpathy-like char-rnn writed in python :)